# How can I get global arrays across files?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, global

How can I get global arrays across files?

I know that I can use $GLOBALS[''] for variables, but what about arrays or even multidimensional arrays?
I need to get the value of arrays those are not in the same file of the script!

Comment: Arrays are variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply define those global and add the array to them..

```
global $somevariableName;
somevariableName = array();
```

globals are just like normal variable you can store anything in them.

Now as of getting them from a different script, you should be able to if the script is included // required, if you want to go something wider you can use databases, or sessions.